# Why does code stop execution when a default value is added to an InputBox method?

Tags: excel, vba, default, exit, inputbox

I have code which asks the user for input.

I use a `Type:=2` `Application.InputBox()` method. I specify the `Prompt`, `Title`, `Default`, and `Type`.

This code stopped execution this morning with no break in the code or error.

I was able to isolate the cause to the `Default` parameter within the `Application.Inputbox` method.

Sample code in which I recreated the issue:

```vb
Sub Test_InputBox_Default()
    Dim Str As String
    
    Str = Application.InputBox("Please enter a string", Title:="INPUTBOX TEST DEFAULT TEXT", Default:="This is just a test", Type:=2)
    Debug.Print Str
    
    Str = Application.InputBox("Please enter a string", Title:="INPUTBOX TEST DEFAULT TEXT", Type:=2)
    Debug.Print Str
End Sub
```

The above code stops before it can print the first string input. If you comment out the first `Application.InputBox` (the one which contains a specification for the `Default` parameter), the code works.

I do not need a `Default` parameter, but I would like to know why it is suddenly causing an issue, having worked before.

Note that I get a syntax error if I include a `Default` parameter in the correct order within the `Application.InputBox` method (without using the `Default:=` syntax). Maybe this has something to do with the issue.

Comment: `Is this a Windows 10 update problem?` - most likely an Office 365 problem, it updates all the time and breaks various things. If you switch `Default` to be positional, then all arguments that come before it must also be switched to positional (`Prompt` and `Title`), please try that.

Comment: The code works fine on Windows 10 64-bit, Office 2019 32-bit. Try GSerg's idea `Str = Application.InputBox("Please enter a string", "INPUTBOX TEST DEFAULT TEXT", "This is just a test", , , , , 2)` or `Str = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter a string", Title:="INPUTBOX TEST DEFAULT TEXT", Default:="This is just a test", Type:=2)`.

Comment: @GSerg thanks for the suggestion. I tried using the positional order for the parameters and I still get the same behavior.

Comment: I've done more testing on this and come to no solid answer or fix, however it does seem isolated to only instances where the `default` is a string variable type. Any double, single, or integer seems to work fine. I have tried converting strings to the `Variant` data type with no luck, either.